# svn:ignore not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I got the following svn-ruke entered via Tortoise-SVN:

> svn:ignore 
>   Debug .
>   bin .
>   obj .
>   pkgobj .
>   pkg .
>   *.suo .
>   (applied recursivly)

But when I commit my folder the /bin/* and /obj/* folders are still committed (throwing tree conflicts) 
Any clue what went wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`svn:ignore` works only for certain commands (such as `svn add`) for unversioned items only. If the folder is already versioned (i.e. in the repository) it will still be committed. You need to `svn delete` it first and commit the delete.